# ServiceStack ResponseFilterAttribute not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net, aop, servicestack

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//Aspect Filters
public class RequestAspectAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute {
  public RequestAspectAttribute() { } //debug point was hit
  public RequestAspectAttribute(ApplyTo applyTo) : base(applyTo) { }
  public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object reqDto) {
      //This code is executed before the service 
      //debug point was hit
  }
}
public class ResponseAspectAttribute : ResponseFilterAttribute {
  public ResponseAspectAttribute() { } //debug point was NOT hit
  public ResponseAspectAttribute(ApplyTo applyTo) : base(applyTo) { }
  public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object resDto) {
      //This code is executed after the service 
      //debug point was NOT hit
  }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//REST Service
[RequestAspect]
[ResponseAspect]
public class TodoService : RestServiceBase<Todo> { ...
```

I am testing out the Req/Res Filter Attributes on the ToDo List sample project with the code above. So nothing else has been changed to the sample project (I think) except for the two additional attributes.

When I add a todo item, only the request attribute was called. The response attribute didn't get triggered.

Shouldn't they fire up in a pair before & after a Rest call in this case? Is my understanding incorrect or am I doing something wrong? Thank you ahead for your help.

Comment: Tom, I used your exact attribute code on my own Rest Service and both breakpoints were hit. That code is fine. Do you have a separate RestServiceBase<Todos> ? If you move the attributes to above the Todo DTO, what are the results?

Comment: Hi Kampsj, do you mean I have a separated TodoService : RestServiceBase<Todo> in a single .cs file? Yes.

Comment: I moved both attributes to the DTO and it works. Even if I move only [ResponseAspect] to Todo DTO, and leave [RequestAspect] at TodoService, it still works. But when they are both at TodoService, the [ResponseAspect] doesn't work. Interesting...However, I want them stay with TodoService if possible, not with DTOs.

Answer (score 0):

Use your request and response filters with respective Request and Response DTO

```
    [Route("/Hello")]
    [RequestAspect]
    public class HelloRequest
    {
        public string hello { get; set; }
    }
    [ResponseAspect]
    public class HelloResponse
    {
        public string hello { get; set; }
    }
    public class HelloService : Service
    {
        public object Any(HelloRequest req)
        {
            return new HelloResponse
            {
                hello = req.hello
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you write an answer based solely on the comment that the OP, Tom, left back in September 2012, which concluded that he got it to work. (`"I moved both attributes to the DTO and it works."`) Then this answer should be community wiki. After all you have not contributed anything new that wasn't discussed 2 years ago. Nor does this solve this requirement: `I want them stay with TodoService if possible, not with DTOs.`