# Can't get custom response filter attribute to trigger

Tags: servicestack, filterattribute

I get the request filter attribute to trigger but the response filter never does. What am I missing?

```
[MyResponse]
[MyRequest]
public class MyService : Service
{
        public object Get(RequestDto request)
        {
            return new {foo = "bar"};
        }
}

public class MyResponseAttribute : ResponseFilterAttribute
{
    public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        var x = requestDto;
    }
}

public class MyRequestAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object responseDto)
    {
        var x = responseDto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this behaviour with the [test I've just added here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/5d308eb7cfe3fd698a659ab2115db1454733e602).

If you still think this is an issue with the framework, can you submit a failing unit test to the project (a pull-request is preferred).

Comment: I ran into the same issue. 
When MyResponseAttribute decorates the Service class, it fails to fire . When MyResponseAttribute is moved to decorate the response DTO instead, it fires. MyRequestAttribute is not affected by this; it fires both when decorating the Service, as well as when decorating the request DTO. I will try to add a failing test.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338894/servicestack-responsefilterattribute-not-being-called